# Member Since date is now the same as Start date since upgrade to 4.7.3

Tags: civimember, issues

For user self sign-ups, the 'Member Since' date is now the same as 'Start date' since a version upgrade to 4.7.3.

Was this expected? There appears to be no way to determine the actual join date now, except to look at the contribution date.

Reports and dashboard widgets which rely on this field are also affected.

Comment: It's a little hard for me to follow what you're asking without more detail.  Could you please give an example, along with the expected behavior and whether that behavior existed prior to CiviCRM 4.7?

Comment: Did the member_since dates on all existing memberships get changed since upgrade to appear the same as the join date, or only on new memberships? Around the time of the upgrade did you change from a Fixed to a Rolling Membership Type Plan?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This is just affecting new memberships. We haven't changed any membership settings (or any others actually) since upgrading.

When a new member joined, they used to have the 'member since' date set to that day's date. Now, post upgrade, this is always set to 1st Jan which is the same as our membership period start date.

Comment: Hello, is there any additional info that would be useful here? Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue since upgrade to 4.7.7 from 4.6.14. It is only happening with Credit Card front-end submissions. If submission is Pay Later, once contribution is set to complete, the correct dates are set for the Membership record. Richard- Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I see ticket in JIRA for this. Seems like core team are having trouble replicating though. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18503

Comment: Confirmed. Also experiencing this.